# How to get a string within a "parenthesized" string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying out code snippets since I am a beginner. I need to get a string from a string with parentheses. For example, a `'foo'` from a string `'(foo)'`. Any efficient way to do this? RegExp will do.

Comment: Yes.  RegExp will do. Did you try ?

Comment: How do you do it? I don't know

Comment: You need to try something.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression that matches everything inside a single pair of round brackets would work:

```
'(foo)'.match(/\((.*)\)/) // -> ["(foo)", "foo"]
```

But usually you want to exclude brackets instead:

```
'(foo)'.replace(/[()]/g, '') // -> 'foo'
```

Comment: What does `.*` mean again?

Comment: @hmpphep [try this for a start](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=regex+.*&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=kMPoWIzzOvHt8AeXuKkg)